# How to add msix to WIX bundle installer

Tags: uwp, wix, windows-installer, msix

We have WIX bundle including several msi packages. Now we want add UWP app.
WIX bundle supports exe, msi, msp and msu packages. But not msix.
So question is: is there a way to include msix package into WIX bundle.

Comment: Could you translate this page to wix exe tags? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-universal-windows-apps-with-the-winappdeploycmd-tool

Comment: Or powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/powershell-msix-cmdlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5422) to implement just such a thing (don't mind the issue title: AppX is the old name for MSIX). The feature just needs someone to design and implement or fund the design and implementation.